# How a Renounced Ownership token makes money for the creator?

Tags: contract-deployment

This is a simple (newbie) question, lets say one creates a token, renounces ownership and starts the initial selling of it. How would the creator make money?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of royalties could be separated from ownership.

For example the [ERC-2981: NFT Royalty Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981) allows to define who will receive royalties depending on the `tokenId`.